# Render page after XMLHttpRequest POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a hard time rendering a page after a XMLHttpRequest POST.

On my client side I do the following:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = window.location.origin + "/mypath";

http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log('you should be redirected or render a new page);
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
http.send(JSON.stringify(myParams));
```

and server side:

```
router.get("/info", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.render('info', {msg: req.query.msg});
})
router.post("/mypath", (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
    res.send(res.redirect(url.format({
        pathname:"/info",
        query: {msg:'my message'}
    })));
})
```

Using the above code doesn't redirect to the info page. What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I don't want my user to see the query msg in his browser navigation bar but just `/info`.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can't redirect pages from server side when performing ajaxes, what you can do is to change the url from client side when condition is in a state you wish to , any way you can redirect from client by using below command .

```
let baseUrl = window.location.origin
window.location.replace(baseUrl + '/info');
```